# Проблема при скачивании aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, pip, установка, python-3.12

Решил поставить себе aiogram, но при установке вышла ошибка. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить.

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: исправил обращение

Comment: В общем-то в тексте ошибки всё и описано. Для компиляции при установке пакета нужны Microsoft C++ Build Tools

Comment: Т.е мне установить build tools и попробовать снова установить aiogram?

Comment: Проще откатить версию Python до версии 3.11, пока основные пакеты не обновили для новой версии Python.